# Website oversize image printing, user-defined dimensions

Tags: php, printing

I am developing a website that must allow the user to click on a **PRINT** button to print specific images on offer on the website (.jpg format).

The user must then be prompted to select printing dimensions (the proportions would be fixed to be the same as the image, *which will vary*), up to a maximum size of 40 inches in either dimension.

**THIS IS THE HARD PART:** if the image is larger than letter format (8.5 x 11) then **the image must print over several pages** to add up to the user-selected dimension.

TO GET FANCY (OPTIONAL): the printing margin should be set to the minimum possible value to save on paper.

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" /> 
    computer image upload: 
    <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
    Web image upload (URL):
    <input type="text" name="url" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="upload"/> 
    </form>
```

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // SETTINGS
    $thumbwidth = 100;
    $deleteDays = 1;

    $size['letter']['width'] = 21.59;
    $size['letter']['height'] = 27.94;    

    $size['a4']['width'] = 21.0;
    $size['a4']['height'] = 29.7;    

    // A4     210 x 297
    // Letter 215.9 x 279.4
    // 1 inch = 2.54 cm

    $inch = 2.54;

    $border = 2.54;

    function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width) {       
         $arr = getimagesize($src);
        /* read the source image */
        switch ($arr['mime']) {
            case 'image/jpeg' : $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
            case 'image/png' : $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;            
            case 'image/gif' : $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;               
            default: $ext = '';
        } 

        $width = imagesx($source_image);
        $height = imagesy($source_image);

       /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
        $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));

        /* create a new, "virtual" image */
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);

        /* copy source image at a resized size */       imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);

       switch ($arr['mime']) {
            case 'image/jpeg' : imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest); break;
            case 'image/png' : imagepng($virtual_image,$dest); break;            
            case 'image/gif' : imagegif($virtual_image,$dest); break;               
            default: $ext = '';
        } 
        /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
        imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_POST['url']=='') {

        $target_path = "images/";                
        $large = $target_path . date('YmdHis').'_'.session_id().'.'.substr(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']),-3); 
        $thumb = $target_path . date('YmdHis').'_'.session_id().'_thumb.'.substr(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']),-3);         

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $large)) {
            make_thumb($large,$thumb,$thumbwidth);
        } 
    }
    elseif (strlen($_POST['url'])>0) {
        $arr = getimagesize($_POST['url']);

        $ext = '';
        switch ($arr['mime']) {
            case 'image/jpeg' : $ext = 'jpg'; break;
            case 'image/png' : $ext = 'png'; break;            
            case 'image/gif' : $ext = 'gif'; break;               
            default: $ext = '';
        } 

        if ($ext != '') {
            $file = 'images/'.date('YmdHis').'_'.session_id();
            $fh = fopen($file.'.'.$ext,'w+');
            $img = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
            fwrite($fh,$img);
            fclose($fh);
            make_thumb($file.'.'.$ext,$file.'_thumb.'.$ext,$thumbwidth);
        }
    }
?>
        if (ratio == 'yes') {
            document.getElementById('imgheight').readOnly = true;
             <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['print'])) {
            $arr = getimagesize('images/'.str_replace('_thumb','',$_GET['print']));

            echo 'x = '.$arr[0].';';
            echo 'y = '.$arr[1].';';            
        }
     ?>
         width = document.getElementById('imgwidth').value;
         one = x/width;
         height = y/one;
         if (height > 0) {
             document.getElementById('imgheight').value = height.toFixed(2);
        }

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('imgheight').readOnly = false;            
        }
    }

    function calc() {
         if(document.getElementById('imgheight').readOnly == true) {
     <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['print'])) {
            $arr = getimagesize('images/'.str_replace('_thumb','',$_GET['print']));

            echo 'x = '.$arr[0].';';
            echo 'y = '.$arr[1].';';            
        }
     ?>
         width = document.getElementById('imgwidth').value;
         one = x/width;
         height = y/one;
         if (height > 0) {
             document.getElementById('imgheight').value = height.toFixed(2);
        }
         }
    }
</script>
```

```
<?php
if (count($_GET)==0) {
 ?>

PRINT RESIZER

Upload Images Below

(Web or Computer-Based)

<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />

COMPUTER-based image upload:<br />
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />

WEB-based image upload (URL):<br />
<input type="text" name="url" />

<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="upload"/>

</form>
Images Uploaded This Session
(Click on Image to Resize and/or Print)
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strstr($file,session_id().'_thumb.')) {
            echo '<a href="?print='.$file.'"><img src="images/'.$file.'" /></a>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
}
else if (isset($_GET['print'])) {
    echo '<img src="images/'.$_GET['print'].'" />';
    ?>
    <form action="?printview" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $_GET['print'];?>" />
    <p style="display: none;">Paper size: <select name="format"><option value="letter" selected>Letter</option><option value="a4">A4</option></select></p>
    <p>Image Ratio: <input type="radio" name="ratio" value="yes" checked onClick="manage(this.value);"/>Keep   <input type="radio" name="ratio" value="no" onClick="manage(this.value);"/>Ignore</p>                
    <p  style="display: none;">Image measurements: <select name="meassure"><option value="in" selected>inch</option><option value="cm">cm</option></select></p>
    <p>Image Width: <input type="text" name="width" id="imgwidth" onKeyUp="calc();"/></p>
    <p>Image Height: <input type="text" name="height" id="imgheight" readonly/></select></p>

    <input type="submit" />   
    </form>
    <?php
}
elseif(isset($_GET['printview'])) {

 ?>

<img src="images/<?php echo $_POST['image'];?>" /><br />
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.print();" value="Print the large Image" />
</div>
 <?php
}
elseif(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $parts = explode('_',$file);

            if ($parts[0]<date('YmdHis',strtotime('-'.$deleteDays.' days'))) {
                unlink ('images/'.$file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
}
?>

<?php
// PHOTO PRINT END
?>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['printview'])) {

    $_POST['image'] = str_replace('_thumb','',$_POST['image']);
    if ($_POST['meassure']=='in') {
        $imgWidth = $_POST['width']*$inch;
        $imgHeight = $_POST['height']*$inch;        
    }
    else {
        $imgWidth = $_POST['width'];   
        $imgHeight = $_POST['height']*$inch;        
    }

    if ($_POST['format']=='letter') {
        $maxPageWidth = $size['letter']['width'] - (2*$border);
        $maxPageHeight = $size['letter']['height'] - (2*$border);        
    }
    else {
        $maxPageWidth = $size['a4']['width'] - (2*$border);
        $maxPageHeight = $size['a4']['height'] - (2*$border);        
    }

 // echo "$imageX = ceil($imgWidth/$maxPageWidth);
   // $imageY = ceil($imgHeight/$maxPageHeight); ";
    $imageX = ceil($imgWidth/$maxPageWidth);
    $imageY = ceil($imgHeight/$maxPageHeight); 
//    echo '<p>'.$imageX.':'.$imageY.'</p>';

    $w = ($size[$_POST['format']]['width']-(2*$border)).'cm';
    $h = ($size[$_POST['format']]['height']-(2*$border)).'cm';
   ?> 
    <style type="text/css">

@media print{

    .img {
        height: <?php echo $h;?>;
        width: <?php echo $w;?>;    
        overflow: hidden;       
        float:left;
        page-break-before: always;
    }
    .fimg {
        height: <?php echo $h;?>;
        width: <?php echo $w;?>;    
        overflow: hidden;       
        float:left;
    }

     body { 
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #canvas, #preview { 
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen{

    .img {
        height: <?php echo $h;?>;
        width: <?php echo $w;?>;    
        overflow: hidden;       
        float:left;
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    .fimg {
        height: <?php echo $h;?>;
        width: <?php echo $w;?>;    
        overflow: hidden;       
        float:left;
    }



    #printing { display: none;
    }
}

</style>
<div id="printing">
    <?php

    for($x=0; $x<$imageX; $x++) {
        for ($y=0; $y<$imageY; $y++) {
            if ($x==0 && $y==0) {
                echo '<div class="fimg">';
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="img">';   
            }

            echo '
<img src="images/'.$_POST['image'].'" style="width: '.$_POST['width'].$_POST['meassure'].';height: '.$_POST['height'].$_POST['meassure'].'; position: relative; top: -'.($y*$maxPageHeight).'cm; left: -'.($x*$maxPageWidth).'cm" /></div>';
        }
    }
   echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Instead of a user-upload, I want this to apply to the image the user just clicked on.
`<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />

computer image upload:<br />

<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />

Web image upload (URL):<br />

<input type="text" name="url" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="upload"/>

</form>`

Comment: Edit your question please don't post all code in the comment